# is it possible to use zabbix log[] key with zabbix_agent2

Tags: logging, log-files, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I have zabbix server 5.4.4 on my linux ubuntu 20.04
Also on my client machine i have installed zabbix_agent2 for 5.4.4 ( there is no zabbix_agent 1 running nor installed )
And zabbix_sender 5.4.4

Im trying to make a new item with log[] key

Using this article: https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/log_items

I changed the configuration file and added server active ip and hostname of the host.

i made a new item with key `logrt[/var/log/syslog,error]`
Type: Zabbix agent (active)
typeof information: log

i go to the host and latest data but i did not see any.

also i changed the key to logrt[/var/log/syslog] so it can feed any new lines in the log file to the zabbix server, but still i did not get any info

i try

```
# zabbix_agent2 -t log[/var/log/syslog]
```

but this is the response

```
log[/var/log/syslog]                          [m|ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED] [The "log" key is not supported in test or single passive check mode]
```

And now i am stuck.
Can someone help me how to make it work?

Comment: Is your log item valid?

Comment: What do you mean by that ?
it is normal linux syslog file (/var/log/syslog)
you can use `cat`, `tail -f` and other tools to open and read it

Comment: you created the log item in zabbix. If you dig that item up in the host configuration, in the zabbix GUI, does it show as valid? If not, it gives a reason when you hover above the 'invalid' icon.

Answer (score 2):

looking closely at:

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/5.0/en/manual/config/items/itemtypes/zabbix_agent/zabbix_agent2

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/en/manual/config/items/plugins#plugins-supplied-out-of-the-box

the zabbix_agent2 supports:

- log
- log.count
- logrt
- logrt.count

however when you try to test it with agent binary:

```
# echo blabla > /tmp/lala
# /usr/sbin/zabbix_agent2 -t 'vfs.file.contents[/tmp/lala]'
vfs.file.contents[/tmp/lala]                  [s|blabla]

# /usr/sbin/zabbix_agent2 -t 'log[/tmp/lala,error]'
log[/tmp/lala,error]                          [m|ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED] [The "log" key is not supported in test or single passive check mode]
```

It is as the message states: `"log" key is not supported in test or single passive check mode`

so since developers for Zabbix did not implement `-t` or `-test` switch for items related to log checking - you simply cannot check it on command line, however if you configure the log monitoring and user `zabbix` is able to access given file - it will work as expected.

If you really need that check option - feel free to submit feature request to zabbix via their public JIRA.